# Activate a device owner using NFC on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, nfc, android-5.0-lollipop, device-policy-manager

I am trying to set the device owner package on a device using NFC. The is mentioned in the Lollipop overview [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise):

> To deploy and activate a device owner, you must perform an NFC data
>   transfer from a programming app to the device while the device is in
>   its unprovisioned state. This data transfer sends the same information
>   as in the provisioning intent described in Managed provisioning.

The reason is once this is set you can use the screen pinning feature to lock the device in a kiosk mode. I have been able to test the this kiosk mode by manually setting the device owner by placing a device_owner.xml file to data/system/ on a rooted device.

I have never used NFC before so I may be way off but I came up with the following NdefMessage based on the info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#MIME_TYPE_PROVISIONING_NFC):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.my.package");
properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID, "MyWiFiSSID");
properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD, "WifiPassword");
properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM, "C9AD9E082457819B54CF76255A400375E4127112");
properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION, "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/xxx/app-release.apk");


ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
out.writeObject(properties);
byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createMime(DevicePolicyManager.MIME_TYPE_PROVISIONING_NFC, yourBytes);
NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
```

Sending this to a device that I have just restored with the Lollipop preview causes it to show:

> Oops! Couldn't set up your device. Contact your IT department.

Its seems to be recognising the fact that it is receiving a provision request, but I do not think it is reading the properties I set, it does not try to connect the the wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you need to use the `Properties.store` to correctly create the bytes for the NdefRecord.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(...);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
properties.store(out, "");
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(DevicePolicyManager.MIME_TYPE_PROVISIONING_NFC, bytes));
```

Currently, I'm having an issue with it downloading my APK and the checksum failing. Not at all sure why.

Comment: I posted my own question regarding the checksum failing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509770/provisioning-in-android-lollipop

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to get this to work over NFC too. I installed a simple app on my Nexus 4 (KitKat) with an activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.deviceowner.app");
        properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION, "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=........");
        properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM, "6ee735dfb8090ab1862fecce430864e21a0e37");
        properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID, "wlan");
        properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD, "XXXXXX");
        properties.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE, "WPA2");

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(properties);
        byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createMime(DevicePolicyManager.MIME_TYPE_PROVISIONING_NFC, yourBytes);
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(msg, this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I flashed my Nexus 7 flashed with the Lollipop preview image (razor-lpx13d-preview-ae4f461f.tgz) and gave it an NFC bump with the Nexus 4 when the Nexus 7 was un-provisioned (no setup - fresh after flashing) and got the same error message:

> Oops! Couldn't set up your device. Contact your IT department.

Then I tried the same thing but this time after running through the initial device setup on the Nexus 7 (to the point where I could see the home screen). This time I got the message

> Oops! This device is already set up

But this time, I was able to see some logging as I was able to setup USB debugging on the Nexus 7:

```
10-22 10:31:29.947    2610-2610/? D/NfcService﹕ LLCP Activation message
10-22 10:31:29.947    2610-2610/? I/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ LLCP activated
10-22 10:31:29.947    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ onP2pInRange()
10-22 10:31:29.954    2610-2610/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
10-22 10:31:29.962      184-547/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
10-22 10:31:29.962      184-547/? D/ACDB-LOADER﹕ ACDB -> send_afe_cal
10-22 10:31:29.962      184-547/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
10-22 10:31:29.974      184-547/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
10-22 10:31:29.981    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ Last registered callback is not running in the foreground.
10-22 10:31:29.987    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ Disabling default Beam behavior
10-22 10:31:29.987    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ mMessageToSend = null
10-22 10:31:29.987    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ mUrisToSend = null
10-22 10:31:29.996    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ Took 48 to get first LLCP PDU
10-22 10:31:30.599    3224-3224/? I/wpa_supplicant﹕ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
10-22 10:31:31.741    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ onP2pReceiveComplete()
10-22 10:31:31.751    2610-2610/? D/NfcService﹕ mock NDEF tag, starting corresponding activity
10-22 10:31:31.751    2610-2610/? D/NfcService﹕ TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.Ndef]
10-22 10:31:31.757    2610-3275/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
10-22 10:31:31.770     549-2765/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.android.nfc/.NfcRootActivity (has extras)} from uid 1027 on display 0
10-22 10:31:31.795    7237-7237/? D/ManagedProvisioning﹕ Device owner provisioning activity ONDESTROY
10-22 10:31:31.827    2610-3275/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
10-22 10:31:31.848     549-2335/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED typ=application/com.android.managedprovisioning cmp=com.android.managedprovisioning/.DeviceOwnerProvisioningActivity (has extras)} from uid 1027 on display 0
10-22 10:31:31.886    7237-7237/? D/ManagedProvisioning﹕ Device owner provisioning activity ONCREATE
10-22 10:31:31.887    7237-7237/? E/ManagedProvisioning﹕ Device already provisioned.
10-22 10:31:31.903    7237-7237/? D/ManagedProvisioning﹕ Device owner provisioning activity ONRESUME
10-22 10:31:32.011      549-621/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.android.managedprovisioning/.DeviceOwnerProvisioningActivity: +149ms (total +200ms)
10-22 10:31:32.955    2610-2610/? D/NfcService﹕ LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
10-22 10:31:32.955    2610-2610/? I/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ LLCP deactivated.
10-22 10:31:32.955    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ Debounce timeout
10-22 10:31:32.955    2610-2610/? D/NfcP2pLinkManager﹕ onP2pOutOfRange()
```

So it does seem that the Device Owner NFC bump can only happen on an unprovisioned device. I appreciate this doesn't answer your question, but the log output might help. Getting hold of the source code for DeviceOwnerProvisioningActivity would certainly help.

Comment: I got this to work with the answer posted by @Randy - but I am now stuck at the same point: `Couldn't use the admin app due to a checksum error. Contact your IT department`

Comment: Were you able to successfully provision wifi settings? When I do it it sits there saying "Connecting to Wi-Fi..." but never connects.

Comment: No, I removed the wifi settings, entered them in the first setup screen, then did the NFC bump. That's when I got the checksum error. Did you get any further with that?

Comment: Nope. I tried putting the wifi settings in just so it would auto connect and I wouldn't have to manually enter the credentials (cause I'm lazy), but it failed to connect to wifi. When I removed the wifi settings it would require me to manually connect to wifi. Once I manually connected it would download the APK but the checksum failed every time.

Comment: Any luck on this wifi? i got the same 'connecting' problem even though i can see the wifi icon as connected

Comment: Same issue here with the Wifi. If I enter the wifi security type, an exception seems to occur. Without this parameter I have an infinite 'Connecting'.
Not sure about the format.

Comment: I am also facing same issue with following code:
    p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID, "-----");
p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD, "----");
It seems it is getting connected with WiFi but stuck on Connecting to Wi-fi... Screen.

Any success on this?

Answer (score 1):

You should enter the WiFi parameters manually. There is a bug that has been corrected in Android 5.1.