# How do I get the signature checksum of my APK?

Tags: android, provisioning, device-policy-manager, device-owner, android-for-work

I would like to use the signature checksum instead of the package checksum when provisioning a device with a device owner app. The app will be downloaded from an http server.

This post is great when using EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM:
[Checksum Error while provisioning Android Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509770/checksum-error-while-provisioning-android-lollipop)

But I would like to use EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM.
See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.htm

The provisioning app and device owner app will both on be running on Android O.

How do I get the signature checksum of my app that I can use in my key/value pair for NFC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile [path_to_your_apk] | grep -Po "(?<=SHA256:) .*" | xxd -r -p | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr -- '+/=' '-_'
```

In details:

- `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile [path_to_your_apk]` extracts informations about the certificate of the APK,
- `grep -Po "(?<=SHA256:) .*" | xxd -r -p` takes the SHA256 hash and converts it to binary,
- `openssl base64` encodes it with base64,
- `tr -d '=' | tr -- '+/=' '-_'` makes it URL-safe (`+` is encoded as `-`, `/` is encoded as `_` and the padding character `=` is removed).

Comment: Your first step returns, "Not a signed jar file".

Comment: I am signing my APK with the V2 signing scheme since these apps will only be run on Android O or greater. If I sign them with the V1 signing scheme, this method works great! I think this is a good and valid answer for the V1 scheme. I will open a new question more specific for the V2 scheme.

Comment: For reference, here is [the new question about V2 signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855952/how-do-i-get-the-signature-checksum-of-my-apk-that-is-signed-with-only-the-v2-sc) that has been answered.

Comment: When I run this command it run and did not give any error but nothing is shown in result  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin>keytool -list -printcert -jarfile "TestDPC_4005.apk" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe"  -Po "(?<=SHA256:) .*" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xxd.exe" -r -p | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe" base64 | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tr.exe" -d '=' | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tr.exe" -- '+/=' '-_'

Comment: Is the URL required the https or http is okay.