# how to get ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM or ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM of my apk?

Tags: android, provisioning, device-owner, device-policy-manager, android-for-work

I'm trying to device owner enrollment via QrCode with the example provided by google of Testdpc
so I downloaded the APK from the link provided on his repository [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc) and set it on my ISS windows machine then I'm trying to get the CHECKSUM to put it on my Qr-Code json

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME":"com.afwsamples.testdpc/com.afwsamples.testdpc.DeviceAdminReceiver",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM":"MS4-Pz8gP0VDPy0-P2I-Pz4NClE-Pz80Pz8rPz9zfD8-DQo=",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION":"http://192.168.1.224/TestDPC_8001.apk"
```

}

I tried the different solutions on the internet [V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855952/how-do-i-get-the-signature-checksum-of-my-apk-that-is-signed-with-only-the-v2-sc) [V1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836891/how-do-i-get-the-signature-checksum-of-my-apk) but it always returns a different ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM from the ones that are provided in google repository [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc)

so any solution to extract the exact PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM?
or extract PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM because it can replace PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM

Answer (score 0):

## Instructions:

1. Download and install strawberry-perl on your operating system. For windows operating system you can download from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/padre-perl-ide/downloads).
2. Now open **command prompt**.
3. Run command >> **cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin** (path of your java jdk bin directory)
4. Now run command >> **keytool -list -printcert -jarfile *YOUR_APK_FILE_PATH* | perl -nle "print $& if m{(?<=SHA256:) .*}" | xxd -r -p | openssl base64 | tr -- '+' '-_'**

Follow this instructions correctly and you will get the correct checksum of your apk file. You can try testing checksum for the **TestDPC** apk file.