# Device Owner on Android 5.0 (and others) whitout rooted devices, device provisioning by NFC

Tags: android, nfc, android-5.0-lollipop, provisioning

I need to know how to set my application as Device owner in Android 5.0, 4.4 and 4.3(?). I've yet tried the method for rooted devices ([described in there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner)), successfully. I saw that works great in android 5.0 and 4.4.2 emulator and in CyanoGen AOSP 4.4.4 (all rooted devices). But I must need to try this on other non rooted devices, in Android 5.0 Developer API you can read this

> "To deploy and activate a device owner, you must perform an NFC data
>   transfer from a programming app to the device while the device is in
>   its unprovisioned state."

but I don't understand what it means, or better, what I've to do. Can someone help me, or explain me the step to do?

PS. I know what NFC is and how it works but I can't understand how to use for this issue.

Comment: See [Activate a device owner using NFC on Android Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26467321/2425802).

Comment: TK a lot i've yet tried previously and i've got some issue caused from my device's nfc chip. I changed device and this now work fine.

Comment: https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea/issues/77 this helped me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a NFC trigger application and install that on a device (other than the one on which you want to make your app as device owner) having NFC.

Following is the code for NFC trigger

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CreateNdefMessageCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        try {
            Properties p = new Properties();

            p.setProperty(
                    DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME,
                    "apk package name");
            p.setProperty(
                    DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION,
                    "app download url");
            p.setProperty(
                    DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM,
                    "apk checksum");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            OutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            p.store(out, "");
            final byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                    DevicePolicyManager.MIME_TYPE_PROVISIONING_NFC, bytes));
            return msg;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For checksum run following command

> cat your_device_owner_app_name.apk | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '='​

- Paste the generated checksum in NFC trigger code.
- Compile and run NFC trigger app on device.

Now upload your application apk which you want to make as device owner on google drive or dropbox.

Take a fresh device or factory reset the device on which you want to set your application as device owner.

Reboot the device and on first screen bring your device containing NFC trigger application and touch for beam transfer.

Your application will be downloaded and will get installed as device owner.

Comment: Yes, this work, I tried it and is well. this was what I need and in this days I tried other method with NFC and without. I Just found a method to provision without root and without using NFC tag and then  I go for testing that

Comment: @alex_au can you please share the new way you found, thank you

Comment: yes sure, you have to replicate the TAG_DISCOVERED action in new intent, and in this put the extras: `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG`, `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES` and `NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID`, with the correct value, I have created this intent referring the Intent that android send when new TAG is Discovered, and I populate them with correct data.

Comment: Another solution for development is to use [adb shell dpm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27909315/1489493). No root, NFC or even two devices required.

Comment: Hi @Spynet, i have used same code for installing device owner app using NFC triggering application, but it gives me the couldn't setup your admin app due to CheckSum error Please let me know where i am doing wrong.
I have posted code in second Comments:

Comment: Properties p = new Properties(); p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME,"com.marakana.android.devicepolicydemo");p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION,"https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mpolgzm0nufnd6/DevicePolicyDemo_2.1.apk?dl=0");
p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM,"4tEyGrxvIf9XBgGHxneg62a6hAQ");

Comment: Hi @Sunil Jain, your checksum is correct. In your dropbox url replace dl=0 with dl=1 and then try again. :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Spynet it's worked and app is install successfully.....could you let me know what should i do to enable app like camera etc. because when device is setup only few apps are installed showing in Running app list.
Thanks Once Again

Comment: @Sunil Jain, I am figuring that out will let you know why they are not present after provisioning :)
Plz upvote the answer :)

Comment: Hi @alex_au i have installed device owner app with NFC, now i want to install it without NFC could you let me know how you have installed device owner app without NFC, i have tried options that you have mentioned in comment but did not get success.....

Comment: @sunil jain you can use "adb shell dpm" command :)
Link: http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html

Comment: Another solution needs rooting of device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner/26839548#26839548

Comment: @Spynet, it's showing only a few apps installed but when i tried to install any system app from google play market, it got installed...

Comment: Hi @alex_au, did you get success to make device owner without using NFC.

Comment: Hello, did any of you figure out how to enable apps such as camera?

Comment: @Spynet Can we update it  OTA after making device owner, I have posted a seperate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041832/ota-updates-for-device-owner-applicationkiosk-mode

Answer (score 1):

If it's needed, it's also possible to set a device-owner with adb as mentioned here:
http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-3-android-lollipop

Comment: It's better to describe the solution here and give attribution to the original source.