# Device Owner without using NFC in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, nfc, android-5.0-lollipop, device-owner

I want to make my app as Device Owner without using NFC. On developer blog it's mentioned that to make device owner you must use NFC but I found it is also possible without NFC as mentioned by alex_au in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906210/device-owner-on-android-5-0-and-others-whitout-rooted-devices-device-provisio/27009164?noredirect=1#comment44588977_27009164).

I have tried this but haven't been successful. Has anybody been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use command line tool **dpm** from adb shell.

**Usage:**

```
usage: dpm [subcommand] [options]
usage: dpm set-device-owner <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm set-profile-owner <COMPONENT> <USER_ID>

dpm set-device-owner: Sets the given component as active admin, and its package as device owner.
dpm set-profile-owner: Sets the given component as active admin and profile owner for an existing user.
```

For more information check: [dpm shell command](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html)

Note: Before using this command make sure that device is not provisioned. If device is provisioned and you get message like "Device is already provisioned" try the command after removing all the accounts from device or try after factory resetting the device.

Comment: it's good for development but we can not use it for production use.

Comment: Yes @Spynet but how end user use it if they want to make my app as device owner

Comment: Hi @Sunil Jain currently there is no such way to make your application as device owner in production. It is only for company-owned devices where IT administrators can start with a new device and configure it with a device owner. Employers can issue these devices with a device owner app already installed that can configure global device settings.
Google might provides the Non NFC provisioning mechanism in future release :)