# Device owner issue using adb method with LG devices only

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, device-owner

I have been trying to get device owner, inspired by [google sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DeviceOwner)

Using adb, I am able to get device owner on nexus 4,5,7,9 and micromax. However in LG G Pad (LG-V400) and LG G3 (LG G3 855) I get an error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN.
```

I noticed that the device admin is enabled on these devices, but not the device owner. I was able to capture the bug report from the device found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pcRab4JKQJZ3pNc29vTjN1cFk/view?usp=sharing).[image]

I have tried contacting LG but havent heard back anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussions and help from Kash, we realized that my original answer was only a portion of what needed to be done to change the device owner. The steps to set the owner are as follows:

1. Root the LG device. Here is the tool I used: http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-root-lg-firmwares-kitkat-lollipop-t3056951
2. Use the command: "set Settings.Secure.USER_SETUP_COMPLETE=0" as root
3. Install your device owner app
4. Create xml file as per this: [How to make my app a device owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner/27909315#answer-26839548)

Reboot the device and it should now work. If you have any questions feel free to send me a message.

Comment: can you tell me exactly when do you run this command? This is what I did: Reset the device, setup the device (without configuring play services). Then I run Settings.secure command, then adb install my device owner app and run the dpm command. I get the same error. Any help?

Comment: Take note, we havent found a solution without rooting. I have contacted LG but there has been no response so far...

Comment: `Settings.Secure.USER_SETUP_COMPLETE` normally becomes true when you set up a user account after a factory reset.  Have you tried resetting and skipping the account setup?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede
Yes, I did try to get become device owner without setup of any account. We still get the same problem.